# Perl mailer tls error

Tags: perl

```
sub send_mail_via_smtp
{
    my( %p ) = @_;

    eval 'use Net::SMTP::TLS';

    my $repository = $p{session}->get_repository;

    my $smtphost = $repository->get_conf( 'smtp_server' );
    ##my $smtphost = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    if( !defined $smtphost )
    {
        $repository->log( "No STMP host has been defined. To fix this, find the full\naddress of your SMTP server (eg. smtp.example.com) and add it\nas the value of smtp_server in\nperl_lib/EPrints/SystemSettings.pm" );
        return( 0 );
    }


    my $smtp = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
           $smtphost,
        Hello   =>      'server.example.org',
        Port    =>      587,
        User    =>      'Example',
        Password=>      'Example',
        );

    # my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new( $smtphost);

    if( !defined $smtp )
    {
        $repository->log( "Failed to create smtp connection to $smtphost" );
        return( 0 );
    }

    $smtp->mail( $p{from_email} );
    $smtp->to( $p{to_email} );

    # if( !$smtp->recipient( $p{to_email} ) )   
    # {
    #    $repository->log( "smtp server refused <$p{to_email}>" );
    #    $smtp->quit;
    #    return 0;
    # }

    my $message = build_email( %p );
    my $data = $message->as_string;
    # Send the message as bytes, to avoid Net::Cmd wide-character warnings
    utf8::encode($data);
    $smtp->data;
    $smtp->datasend( $data );
    $smtp->dataend;
    $smtp->quit;

    return 1;
}
```

Here is my mailer code but when i run this getting an error

Can't locate object method "new" via package "Net::SMTP::TLS" (perhaps you forgot to load "Net::SMTP::TLS"?)

I tried to use mailer without tls but doesnt work

Comment: drop the `eval` and simply write `use Net::SMTP::TLS;`

Answer (score 2):

after

```
eval 'use Net::SMTP::TLS';
```

add this line

```
die $@ if $@;
```

This should give a message why Net::SMTP::TLS isn't loading